# Serving Docker with NodeJs shows Error : connection refused, How can i resolve

Tags: node.js, docker, express

So i am new to Docker and i am following this tutorial to a point .
https://owen31302.gitbook.io/github-education/digital-ocean/deploy-node-js-on-digitalocean-droplet-using-docker

to set up docker on digital ocean, i followed this
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04

and it worked without trouble

Now here is what, i installed git on the server because i wanted to use git to Clone the web app, then I did

```
git clone https://github.com/EmekaIwuagwu/docker_test1.git
```

and pulled the app into the server with git, then i cd into the folder

```
cd docker_test1
```

then ran docker build command like this

```
docker build . -t digital-ocean-app
```

Now the app built successfully inside the Digitalocean VPS Linux box

running docker images i have this

```
REPOSITORY          TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
digital-ocean-app   latest    d375b6e4c37f   3 minutes ago   122MB
hello-world         latest    9c7a54a9a43c   3 months ago    13.3kB
```

As you can see , there is digital ocean app there

Now i run it like this

```
docker run digital-ocean-app:latest
```

it starts the Node app as seen here

```
root@testdocker:~/docker_test1# docker run digital^Ccean-app:latest
root@testdocker:~/docker_test1# docker run digital-ocean-app:latest

> nodejst1@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node index.js

Example app listening on port 3000!
```

But rather than show in the browser , i am getting Connection refused.

http://167.71.30.198:3000/status

What am i getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it.

Here is a step by step method on how I achieved it.

1.) Create and push the code (Together with the Docker file.) as shown in the Github
For the sake of Clarity i will be sharing here

**Node.js app**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/status", (req, res) => res.send({ status: "I'm alive!" }));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:13-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And push code to Git repo

2.) Login to Digital ocean Linux vps (i used Ubuntu) in my case. And followed setup here to setup everything
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04

3.) Do a Git clone my case , i installed git inside the server then did a Git Clone like this `git clone https://github.com/EmekaIwuagwu/docker_test1.git`

4.) then I do a Docker Build like this `docker build . -t digital-ocean-app`

5.) After which i followed suit by running the final command to run the app inside my server. This is how i ran the server

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 digital-ocean-app
```

6.) Running docker ps
everything is up and fine

Now checking from the browser

[image: james.png]

Answer (score -1):

Docker may not be the top choice for Node.js deployment due to its complexity, performance overhead, and resource usage. This can result in memory leaks and recurrent container downtimes as server load increases. Additionally, it might necessitate a powerful server for scalability.

Alternatively, `you could opt for PM2, a simpler solution for deploying Node.js projects efficiently`.

Comment: PM 2? please assist with this. Is this a cloud provider?

Comment: No, PM2 is not a cloud provider. PM2 is a process manager for Node.js applications. It is used to manage, monitor, and scale Node.js processes, making it easier to deploy and manage Node.js applications on a server or in a production environment.

You just have to install pm2 & run few commands:
Install pm2:  `npm i -g pm2`
To start project:   `pm2 start dist/main.js --name project_name`
To run project automatically on server reboot:  `pm2 startup systemd`
To save configurations:  `pm2 save`   (It'll generate ecosystem.config.js file in ~/.pm2 directory)
To check logs: `pm2 logs`